# Thumbdrive does not show files after write

Tags: 16.04, usb-drive

(possibly) noob question, but I couldn't find this via google so..trying my luck here.

Using ubuntu 16.04, When i write files to a thumbdrive, and i open the thumbdrive in another computer, it does not appear.

Tried with multiple files, they just dont appear as if i never wrote them.

Anyone has a clue whats going on?